# Do I need an object after the following verbs?

Tags: grammar

> Since Mary had neither complained nor lamented [...], I thought our
>   dynamic had been enough for her.

Do I need an object after *complained nor lamented*? Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Complain* and *lament* can be used as intransitive verbs. That's why no direct object is needed. You may add a direct one, since *lament* is also used as a transitive verb, but you don't have to do that:

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/lament

Answer (score 1):

**"[to lament](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lament)"** is both a transitive and an intransitive verb that means *"express regret or disappointment about something"* (**transitive**) and *"to mourn aloud"* (**intransitive**).

- Since Mary had neither complained nor lamented, I thought our dynamic had been enough for her. (**Correct**)